# How to install xamarin android components manually for visual studio 2015 community edition

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am using visual studio 2015 , i need to install xamarin components for android in visual studio offline manually.
How to do this manually (offline installation) ?
can anyone please share the offline components links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/) for Xamarin Android Manual Installation. It includes the steps required to manually install Xamarin.Android